# Is there a difference in the magic used by the black staff and the Druids?

Tags: shannara

In the Word and Void/Shannara series, we see that Knights of the Word can only use magic with the help of the black staff given by the Lady. Much later, the Druids seem to have gained use of magic without the staff. Knights who use the magic also don't have use of it later on in the future, what I felt was kind of a karmic use. Druids don't seem to have this issue.

Is there any difference in the type of magic being deployed by the black staff users, and the druids?

Comment: I had vaguely thought the Druid's magic was inherited from Nest rather than from the Knights.  But it's been a long time since I've read those books.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the key difference is that the staff is a talisman, where as Druid magic comes from within. I recall Terry Brooks stating in many of his novels that magic can come from talismans, people or be naturally ocurring.

Additionally if i recall correctly the staff magic is provided by the Word. It seems likely to me that this would not be the case for Druid magic.